# Legacy Query Sybase to TSQL MSSQL migration with multiple left join with or operator

Tags: sql, join, left-join, sybase

I would like to convert this sybase legacy sql code to ansi tsql new standard for ms sql, but I can't find the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 3 FROM  x_linea_cred, x_linea_cred_priv, x_clt_prd 
 WHERE x_clt_prd.r_client = @rclient AND
      (x_clt_prd.nro_prod *= x_linea_cred.nro_prod or
       x_clt_prd.nro_prod *= x_linea_cred_priv.nro_prod))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a while now, the standard notation for outer join is `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`. Your query should be converted to:

```
select 3
  from x_clt_prd c
  left join x_linea_cred lc on lc.nro_prod = c.nro_prod
  left join x_linea_cred_priv lcp on lcp.nro_prod = c.nro_prod
 where c.r_client = @rclient
```